# Check if String contains substring in clojure

Tags: string, clojure

I need to check if a java String contains a substring in my tests.

This doesn't work because java strings are not collections:

```
(deftest test_8
    (testing "get page from sputnik"
        (let [
            band "Isis"
            page (get-sputnikpage-for-artist band)
            ]
            (is (contains? band "Isis")))));does NOT work
```

Is there a way to convert java strings into collections? Or can I check for substring occurences in other ways?

Comment: Be aware that contains? does NOT check the existence of values, but existence of keys (maps) or indices (vectors and strings). One of the most common pitfalls in Clojure function naming. Both (contains? [1 2] 2) and (contains? "12" 2) => false because neither has an index 2 (only 0 & 1)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `contains` method from `java.lang.String`:

`(.contains "The Band Named Isis" "Isis")`

=> true

You can also do it with regular expressions, e.g.

```
(re-find #"Isis" "The Band Named Isis")
```

=> "Isis"

```
(re-find #"Osiris" "The Band Named Isis")
```

=> nil

If you need your result to be true or false, you can wrap it in `boolean`:

`(boolean (re-find #"Osiris" "The Band Named Isis"))`

=> false

Answer (score 60):

[Clojure 1.8](http://blog.cognitect.com/blog/2016/1/19/clojure-18) has introduced [includes?](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/branch-master/clojure.string-api.html#clojure.string/includes?) function.

```
(use '[clojure.string :as s])
(s/includes? "abc" "ab") ; true
(s/includes? "abc" "cd") ; false
```

Answer (score 6):

Strings are seqable:

```
(seq "Hello") ;;=> (\H \e \l \l \o)
```

... so you *could* use the sequence library to find a match:

```
(defn subsumes [main sub]
  (some
   (partial = (seq sub))
   (partition (count sub) 1 main)))

(subsumes "Hello" "ll") ;;=>> true
```

... but it's simpler and much faster to do [as Diego Basch suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26386877/1562315).